# Offset 3D model to certain volume

Tags: 3d, geometry, offset, volume, area

Let's say, there is arbitrarily complex 3D shape with its V1 volume.
The task it to calculate **uniform offset value**, which could be used to 'scale'
given three-dimensional model to match V2 [another defined volume].

Is there any algorithm or method to do it?
You should thing about this value as shell or peel, which has 
only one thickness overall surface.

[image]

Comment: I've thought that at least surface area/volume ratio is the same in both instances, so it could be potentially a clue, but it's not.